# run ls but skip first 3 files

Tags: command-line, text-processing, ls

Let's say `ls -t` returns:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

How can I skip the first 3 results? So the result is only:

```
4
5
6
```

I am aware I can run `ls -t | head -3` but that will simply take the first 3 lines, but I need to skip the first 3 lines.

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: `ls -t | tail -n+4`

Comment: @FedonKadifeli not interested in rep? :D pLumo is going to run away with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `tail`:

```bsh
ls -tq | tail -n+4
```

Please note that I added `-q` option to `ls` to prevent issues with newlines in filenames. While this might be the default for `ls` output to terminal, it is not the default when piped.

Also note, that this is okay for visual output but not for scripting, as files with newlines won't work, because newlines get replaced by `?`.

In general you should [avoid parsing `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).

Comment: man page answer = rep galore :-)

Comment: is that a bad thing ? ^^ imo answers should be posted as answers....

Comment: Noooooooooo :D It is a good thing. for you ;-)

Comment: aand for OP :-)

Comment: would `ls -t | tail +4` work too? (i.e. no `n` argument)

Comment: It works the same with the Ubuntu version of `tail`, but it's not a standard feature. So better don't get used to it and don't use it if you want portability.